# Azure App Configuration: JavaScript SDK Getting Features From Promise Not Returning Data

Tags: azure, react-typescript, azure-app-configuration

I'm doing a PoC for Azure App Configuration. I created a free instance in our Azure env and added a couple of feature flags. The Issue I am having is with the JavaScript SDK when attempting to fetch feature flags from the App Configuration. Here's the snippet of code that I am using. (NOTE: the app is a React app w/ Typescript)

```
import { AppConfigurationClient } from '@azure/app-configuration';
import { GetConfigurationSettingResponse } from '@azure/app-configuration';

const appConfigClient = new AppConfigurationClient(process.env.REACT_APP_APPCONFIG_CONNECTION_STRING);

const requestFeatureFlags = async (): Promise<GetConfigurationSettingResponse> => {

    const featureFlags = await appConfigClient.getConfigurationSetting({ key: '', label: 'my_feature_flags' });
    console.log(featureFlags);

    return featureFlags;
}

requestFeatureFlags().then((response) => { alert('I am here'); console.log(response) });
```

In the above I can see the request being made in the browser dev console and response with the feature flags, but the `Promise` is never returned from the `await appConfigClient.getConfigurationSetting({ key: '', label: 'my_feature_flags' });` call. The console log of `featureFlags` yields this in the browser console -> [image]

The `alert` inside the `then()` is never fired. So at this point I'm a loss lol. The SDK can be found here ->  npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/app-configuration/v/1.1.0

If anyone else has come across this issue and help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Can you try by changing `return featureFlags` to `return featureFlags.value`? This is based on the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/app-configuration-readme?view=azure-node-latest#create-and-get-a-setting.

Comment: That doesn't work either. `getConfigurationSetting()` has a return type of Promise<GetConfigurationSettingResponse>.

Comment: Im also facing same issue as of 2023. Did you managed to get this to work? @Joseph

Comment: @kuriouskoala no I never got it work, PoC window ended and we went a different route for feature flags which is unfortunate, I had high hopes for this.

Comment: I see, looks like I will need to do the same. What did you ended up using for feature flags? If you dont mind sharing. @Joseph